# Problems with regex in c# only returning a single match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm building a regex and I'm missing something as it's not working properly.
my regex logic is trying to look for anything that has #*anychars*# and return the number of matches on the sentence and not a single match.
Here are a few examples

1- `#_Title_# and #_Content_#` should return two matches: `#_Title_# and #_Content_#`.

2- `Product #_TemplateName_# #_Full_Product_Name_# more text. text text #_Short_Description_#` should return 3 matches: `#_TemplateName_#` `#_Full_Product_Name_#` and `#_Short_Description_#`

and so on. Here is what my regex looks like: `^(.*#_.*_#.*)+$`

any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you matching `#anychars#` of `#_anychars_#`

Comment: I updated the question as the formating was misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something as simple as:

```
#.*?#
```

Or:

```
#_.*?_#
```

If you are trying to match the underscores too (it wasn't clear in the original version of the question). Or:

```
#_(.*?)_#
```

Which makes it easier to extract the token between your `#_` and `_#` delimiters as a group.

Should work. The `*?` is key. It's *non-greedy*. Otherwise you match everything between the first and last `#`

So for example:

```
var str = "Product #_TemplateName_# #_Full_Product_Name_# more text. text text #_Short_Description_#";

var r = new Regex("#_(.*?)_#");

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(str)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value + "\t" + m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Outputs:

```
#_TemplateName_#         TemplateName
#_Full_Product_Name_#    Full_Product_Name
#_Short_Description_#    Short_Description
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "#Title# and #Content#",
                                  "Product #TemplateName# #_Full_Product_Name_# more text. text text #_Short_Description_#"
                              };

            string pattern = "(?'string'#[^#]+#)";

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["string"].Value).ToArray()));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You regular expression is not correct. In addition, you want to loop through match if you want all matching.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "Product #_TemplateName_# #_Full_Product_Name_# more text. text text #_Short_Description_#",
        pattern = "#_[a-zA-Z_]*_#";
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use anchors and change your regex to:

`(#[^#]+#)`

In regex the `[^#]` expression means *any character BUT #*

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = @"(#[^#]+#)";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string sentence = "#blah blah# asdfasdfaf #somethingelse#";

      foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(sentence))
     Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", 
               match.Value, match.Index);
   }
}
```